# Load an remote Operating System to the local machine to work like local operating system

Tags: ubuntu, debian, operating-systems, administrator

Could anyone of you suggest some method(idea) for loading an OS from a remote server to the local machine hard disk. Please see the scenario here, for more clarification.

Imagine one guy has his own company. He has 5 employees and 5 machines, like one machine for each employee. Now he want to setup something like this. Each employee can sit any of the 5 computers. The employees Operating systems have been setup in a server machine in a 'restore to local machine'(something like clone) format. Whenever, an employee switch on the computer in front him, he needs to load his OS from the remote server to his local machine. Which means, here there is no any specific computer for an employee. The employees can sit wherever they like. Only they need to load their corresponding Operating System to the Local machine.

I hope you get the scenario. Please ask if there is any misunderstanding with my explanation.
Please suggest some good ideas to setup the above scenario in a LAN.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a different OS to be available? Or will user accounts being available on any computer for anyone be enough?

Comment: What you are referring to is typically called a 'thin client' these days. The architecture is trickier that a typical network, and up front costs are much higher, but maintenance costs can be substantially lower as the number of clients increases.

Comment: @LeeHarrison A thin client might perform a network boot to load a basic OS, but they're generally not designed to do any computational work and the basic OS is usually designed purely to access some remote server (via screen sharing/remove control, a web browser, etc.) and provide display and input capability. The question seems to be asking more about loading (and saving!) an entire OS, which is different, difficult (though doable if you keep it on a virtual machine, as in one of the answers), and probably not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unusual (though not unheard of) to load entire OSes over the network. The network traffic from that would be rather difficult to manage, let alone other difficulties for day-to-day use. There is network boot (via PXE), though that's more often used to load recovery or installation images and not for a full OS backup/restore on every start.

There are two other technologies that may be more suitable for your use case:

- Remote access/thin clients
- Network/roaming user accounts

---

#### Remote access

Remote access involves running an OS on the server, and either full OSes or thin clients for the users, where they log into a session on the server and effectively only have a local screen, keyboard and mouse - the local machine does no processing or storage. This is not really suitable for tasks that require a lot of computing power (it all runs on the server), but can be an easier way to manage installed programs, and thin clients can be cheaper than full desktop machines.

---

#### Roaming profiles

This means the user's profile, which usually contains all user-specific settings (`/home/username` by default on Linux, and `\Users\username` on Windows) is shared. There are many technologies to do so, dependent on which OS you run. Windows has Active Directory. There are others for Linux, which usually involves mapping a network shared store as the location of the profile. In this setup, all programs are installed locally on the machine, usually with identical images, and the user just carries their profile around with them.

Comment: I've heard of people pxe booting systems off iscsi. Remote access would make more sense to me though, personally especially running off linux.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Depends if you want/have a powerful server or powerful desktop machines. Also depends if you have CPU-intensive stuff, or need to interact with local hardware, or need admin privileges to test stuff (big no-no in a shared-server environment), etc.. I'd say roaming profiles are more common, but that might just be Windows.

Comment: And network speed in some cases. You need to be fast for remote access or network based disk access

Comment: @ Bob: Could you elaborate the second method since I am not that much aware of that or could you suggest some good tutorial on that ?.

Comment: @UvaisIbrahim http://serverfault.com/questions/99348/roaming-user-profiles-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with a hypervisor.

The main OS on a hypervisor can authenticate each person. Once that is done, the chosen OS virtual disk is streamed to them via the network, in some highly compressed form.

This approach helps in performance, because the hypervisor can implement write-back caching, and use the network in a much better way without latency becoming an issue for writes.

Otherwise, a custom solution is probably in order. It could build on the [UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) network stack. UEFI can handle graphics reasonably well, and can be used for authentication. Then their disk is transferred to the system, via something like [iPXE](http://ipxe.org/).

Either way would require careful architecting of the virtual disks so that the kernel and core OS components are small enough in size, which would have to be transmitted in one shot. The rest can be transferred as ordinary files.

Data should be stored entirely on the server.

Comment: Could you suggest some good tutorials on this?

Comment: I'm no expert in this kind of thing. Ask at a place like [reboot.pro](http://reboot.pro).